# Oracle Errors for queries

Tags: oracle

If I type a single statement like `create table t( i int)`, then it displays table created. Again If i write `drop table t` then it shows table dropped. So everything fine till now. Now the problem starts:-

If i write both statements together like

```
create table t(i int);
drop table t;
```

then it shows

> ORA-00911: invalid character

Can't we execute two queries simultaneously in Oracle?

I am using oracle 10 g through Database Home Page option.

Comment: Is this in an Oracle SQL terminal, Toad, or what?

Comment: I'm not sure what "Oracle terminal" means.  Are you talking about the interactive query builder within the Oracle Application Express UI?  Something in Enterprise Manager?  Something else?

Comment: I am using Oracle® Database Express Edition(10g).

Comment: If you are using any interactive window like that of `SQL*Plus`, there shouldn't be any issue. Even for GUI based tools, there won't be an issue. **Can you please elaborate where you are executing the queries?**

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any issue. Even if you copy the two statements together from any editor, and paste it on the interactive window, you should be able to see each of the statements execute one after another. For GUI based tools like `SQL Developer`, `TOAD`, `PL/SQL Developer` etc., you have options like `execute as script` or `command window`. Even if you select both queries and click execute, each of the statements will execute one after another.

Let's see in `SQL*Plus`, I copy pasted both statements together -

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(i INT);

Table created.

SQL> DROP TABLE t;

Table dropped.

SQL>
```

So, no issues.

Let's see in `SQL Developer`, I am executing both statements together as script -

[image]

> Can't we execute two queries simultaneously in Oracle?

If you mean what I have shown above, then, of course yes.

Comment: I am using web interface of oracle database express edition 10 g and it is not allowing to execute code even by selecting.